# What can make this code accomplish my objective of visualizing this pie chart in flutter?

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart, charts

I wanna create a pie chart in flutter.I watched couple of videos on the web and replicated as they did after altering some parameters and arguments.The pie chart that I'm creating is gonna represent the statistics of Recovered,Active and Death cases of Corona virus in India.The data that I'm gonna be using is from https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries

Typically,the pie chart needs 3 legends as mentioned above.I tried implementing this but ran into unconventional errors. I've fetched the data and decoded it with dart but I'm miserably failing to implement it in a pie chart.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
void main()=>runApp(App());

class Task{
  String task;
  int taskvalue;
  Color colors;
  Task({this.task,this.taskvalue,this.colors});
}



class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
home:Home()
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  List<dynamic> data;
  Map<String,dynamic> statsIndia;
  List<charts.Series<Task,String>> _seriesPieData;
  int a,b,c;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull("https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries"), //https://corona-virus-stats.herokuapp.com/api/v1/cases/countries-search
      //https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?global=stats print(data["results"][0]["total_cases"])
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json"
      }

    );

    this.setState(() {
      data = json.decode(response.body);
      statsIndia=data[11];
      a = statsIndia["cases"];
      b=statsIndia["recovered"];
      c = statsIndia["deaths"];
    });

    return "Sucesss!";
  }

get(){


  var piedata=[
    new Task(task: "Confirmed",taskvalue: a,colors:Color(0xFF003cbf)),
    new Task(task: "Recovered",taskvalue: b,colors:Color(0xFF06cafd)),
    new Task(task:"Deaths",taskvalue: c,colors:Color(0xFFff5c4d))

    ];
    _seriesPieData.add(
      charts.Series(
        data:piedata,
        domainFn: (Task task,_)=>task.task,
        measureFn: (Task task,_)=>task.taskvalue,
        colorFn: (Task task,_)=>
        charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(task.colors),
        id:"India",
        labelAccessorFn: (Task row,_)=>'${row.taskvalue}',

      )
    );
}

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getData();
    _seriesPieData=List<charts.Series<Task,String>>();
    get();

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
        child:Padding(
          padding:EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child:Container(
            child:Center(
              child:Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Stats"),
                  Expanded(
                    child:charts.PieChart(
                                    _seriesPieData,
                                    animate: true,
                                    animationDuration: Duration(seconds:5),
                                    behaviors: [
                                      new charts.DatumLegend(
                                        outsideJustification: charts.OutsideJustification.endDrawArea,
                                        horizontalFirst: false,
                                        desiredMaxRows: 2,
                                        cellPadding: new EdgeInsets.only(right:4.0,bottom:4.0),
                                        entryTextStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                                          color:charts.MaterialPalette.purple.shadeDefault,
                                          fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                                          fontSize: 11),
                                        ),

                                    ],
                                    defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(
                                      arcWidth: 50,
                                      arcRendererDecorators: [
                                        new charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
                                          labelPosition: charts.ArcLabelPosition.inside
                                        )
                                      ]
                                    ),
                                  ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            )
          )
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There's no issues from serializing the json.The nightmare lies in visualizing it in a pie chart.So the data which must be utilized to plot the pie chart is stored in statsIndia. I couldn't figure out what's wrong after hours of debugging.The error logs are

```
I/flutter ( 5237): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5237): The following RangeError was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 5237): RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
I/flutter ( 5237):
I/flutter ( 5237): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 5237):   ChartContainer<dynamic>
I/flutter ( 5237):   file:///C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/charts_flutter-0.9.0/lib/src/base_chart_state.dart:89:32
I/flutter ( 5237):
I/flutter ( 5237): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 5237): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:146:60)
I/flutter ( 5237): #1      ArcRenderer.update.<anonymous closure> (package:charts_common/src/chart/pie/arc_renderer.dart:231:39)
I/flutter ( 5237): #2      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:282:8)
I/flutter ( 5237): #3      ArcRenderer.update (package:charts_common/src/chart/pie/arc_renderer.dart:176:16)
I/flutter ( 5237): #4      BaseChart.onPostLayout.<anonymous closure> (package:charts_common/src/chart/common/base_chart.dart:584:37)
I/flutter ( 5237): #5      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
I/flutter ( 5237): #6      BaseChart.onPostLayout (package:charts_common/src/chart/common/base_chart.dart:583:10)
I/flutter ( 5237): #7      BaseChart.layout (package:charts_common/src/chart/common/base_chart.dart:398:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #8      ChartContainerRenderObject.performLayout (package:charts_flutter/src/chart_container.dart:215:12)
I/flutter ( 5237): #9      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #10     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #11     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #12     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #13     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #14     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:11)
I/flutter ( 5237): #15     WidgetLayoutDelegate.performLayout (package:charts_flutter/src/widget_layout_delegate.dart:80:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #16     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #17     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:399:14)
I/flutter ( 5237): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #19     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:808:17)
I/flutter ( 5237): #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #21     RenderPositionedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:394:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #23     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:207:11)
I/flutter ( 5237): #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #25     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:11)
I/flutter ( 5237): #26     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:484:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #27     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #28     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:399:14)
I/flutter ( 5237): #29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #31     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #32     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #33     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1248:11)
I/flutter ( 5237): #34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #35     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #37     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #39     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #41     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #43     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #45     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #46     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #47     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #48     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #49     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #50     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3225:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #52     _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:700:15)
I/flutter ( 5237): #53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #54     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #55     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #56     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #57     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #58     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #59     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #60     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #61     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #62     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #63     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #64     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #65     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #66     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:167:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #67     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1630:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): #68     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:887:18)
I/flutter ( 5237): #69     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:402:19)
I/flutter ( 5237): #70     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:884:13)
I/flutter ( 5237): #71     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:284:5)
I/flutter ( 5237): #72     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1113:15)
I/flutter ( 5237): #73     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1052:9)
I/flutter ( 5237): #74     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:861:7)
I/flutter ( 5237): (elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
I/flutter ( 5237):
I/flutter ( 5237): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: ChartContainerRenderObject<dynamic>#9a7c9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT:
I/flutter ( 5237):   creator: ChartContainer<dynamic> ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
I/flutter ( 5237):     RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ← LayoutId-[<chartContainer>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ←
I/flutter ( 5237):     PieChart<dynamic> ← Expanded ← Column ← Center ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 5237):   parentData: <none> (can use size)
I/flutter ( 5237):   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=395.4, h=651.4)
I/flutter ( 5237):   semantic boundary
I/flutter ( 5237):   size: MISSING
I/flutter ( 5237): This RenderObject has no descendants.
I/flutter ( 5237): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5237): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: ChartContainerRenderObject<dynamic>#9a7c9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 5237): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#7e538 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 5237): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#5b0cd NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 5237): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: ChartContainerRenderObject<dynamic>#9a7c9
I/flutter ( 5237): Another exception was thrown: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
I/flutter ( 5237): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: ChartContainerRenderObject<dynamic>#9a7c9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 5237): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#7e538 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 5237): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#5b0cd NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 5237): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: ChartContainerRenderObject<dynamic>#9a7c9
I/flutter ( 5237): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#5b0cd NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 5237): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: ChartContainerRenderObject<dynamic>#9a7c9

I/flutter ( 5237): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1697 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5237): Another exception was thrown: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
I/flutter ( 5237): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: ChartContainerRenderObject<dynamic>#9a7c9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 5237): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: ChartContainerRenderObject<dynamic>#9a7c9
I/flutter ( 5237): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1697 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true.
I/flutter ( 5237): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: ChartContainerRenderObject<dynamic>#9a7c9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait until all data arrives from api then you can build chart.

following code will work for you.

```
List<dynamic> data = [];
  Map<String, dynamic> statsIndia;
  List<charts.Series<Task, String>> _seriesPieData =
      List<charts.Series<Task, String>>();
  int a, b, c;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(
            "https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries"), //https://corona-virus-stats.herokuapp.com/api/v1/cases/countries-search
        //https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?global=stats print(data["results"][0]["total_cases"])
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    data = json.decode(response.body);
    statsIndia = data[11];
    a = statsIndia["cases"];
    b = statsIndia["recovered"];
    c = statsIndia["deaths"];
    print(a);
    get();
    setState(() {});
    return "Sucesss!";
  }

  get() {
    var piedata = [
      new Task(task: "Confirmed", taskvalue: a, colors: Color(0xFF003cbf)),
      new Task(task: "Recovered", taskvalue: b, colors: Color(0xFF06cafd)),
      new Task(task: "Deaths", taskvalue: c, colors: Color(0xFFff5c4d))
    ];
    _seriesPieData.add(charts.Series(
      data: piedata,
      domainFn: (Task task, _) => task.task,
      measureFn: (Task task, _) => task.taskvalue,
      colorFn: (Task task, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(task.colors),
      id: "India",
      labelAccessorFn: (Task row, _) => '${row.taskvalue}',
    ));
    print(_seriesPieData.length);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Stats"),
                  _seriesPieData.length > 0
                      ? Expanded(
                          child: charts.PieChart(
                            _seriesPieData,
                            animate: true,
                            animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                            behaviors: [
                              new charts.DatumLegend(
                                outsideJustification:
                                    charts.OutsideJustification.endDrawArea,
                                horizontalFirst: false,
                                desiredMaxRows: 2,
                                cellPadding: new EdgeInsets.only(
                                    right: 4.0, bottom: 4.0),
                                entryTextStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                                    color: charts
                                        .MaterialPalette.purple.shadeDefault,
                                    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                                    fontSize: 11),
                              ),
                            ],
                            defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(
                                arcWidth: 50,
                                arcRendererDecorators: [
                                  new charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
                                      labelPosition:
                                          charts.ArcLabelPosition.inside)
                                ]),
                          ),
                        )
                      : Container()
                ],
              ))))),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This was a lifesaver,mahn!!Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there any way I can add this chart to a container of a desired width?

Comment: And how to reduce the size of this expanded widget in order to make it fit into the container that I'm willing to attach this?

Comment: i am not sure but try following. Container(fix height or width)->Column->Expanded->chart.

Comment: Dude! I tried this but it doesn't work.Have any other approaches? :(